# How to add data into data tables

Tags: javascript, json

Let's start off by defining what I have.  I have a remote JSON API, which I call to in order to get some data.  I then run some simple functions on the data and end up with a row of data.  This row of data is split into three variables.  Date, name and message (imagine an IRC chat room).
I wish to display this data in a [data table](http://www.datatables.net/) so that it is searchable however, I am having trouble adding a row to a data table.
At the moment, my HTML looks similar to this:

```
<table id="table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Message</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Message</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

and my JS looks like:

```
    var text = document.getElementById('text'); //Text Div
    var nameguest = data.items[i].from; //Guests
    var nameuser = data.items[i].from.name; //Users
    var message = data.items[i].message; //Messages
    changeDate(data.items[i].date); //Date
    var table = document.getElementById("table"); //Table Div

    var row = table.insertRow(i);
    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = datehuman;
    if (typeof nameguest == "object") {
        row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = nameuser;
    } else {
        row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = nameguest;
    }
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = message;
}
}
```

Is there some similar code to `insertCell(0).innerHTML` for datatables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra "tbody" tag in your table's html. And you can use the following function to insert entries in the table.

```
function insertEntry (tableId, date, name, message) {

    var table = document.getElementById(tableId),
    tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0],
    tr = document.createElement("tr"),
    newDateEntry = document.createElement("td"),
    newNameEntry = document.createElement("td"),
    newMessageEntry = document.createElement("td");

    newDateEntry.innerHTML = date;
    newNameEntry.innerHTML = name;
    newMessageEntry.innerHTML = message;

    tr.appendChild(newDateEntry);
    tr.appendChild(newNameEntry);
    tr.appendChild(newMessageEntry);

    tbody.appendChild(tr);
}
```

Your HTML may look like following:

```
<table id="table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Message</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Message</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Your sample call to the function will look like:

```
insertEntry("table", "1/1/15", "Ayanonly1", "Hellow World");
```

Answer (score 0):

i added a tbody tag in the html provided by you as below

```
<table id="table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Message</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody></tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Message</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

and for adding the data to the table you can use **append** in jquery

```
var nameuser = data.items[i].from.name; //Users    
var message = data.items[i].message; //Messages
var newRowContent="<td>"+nameuser+"</td><td>"+message+"</td>  
       <td>"+changeDate(data.items[i].date)+"</td>"

$("#tblEntAttributes tbody").append(newRowContent);
```

from above code,i stored values in a variable and am appending that to the table tbody

for any more information about append [please click here](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
i hope my answer is helpful.